# In mxgraph inside draw.io we pop up a dialog that has a text area. How to control scroll speed while selecting?

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

Thank you for making mxgraph and draw.io open source.  We have been extending it to enhance productivity.

One thing we did was add a dialog box that pops up, where you can enter a text description.

However, after you enter a lot of text, and then want to edit it, you need to be able to select just a portion.  You do this by using the mouse, click at a point in the text and then move the cursor to select more.

The issue is that while doing this, as soon as you get to the top or bottom of the text area, it zooms at super-human speed to the very beginning or very end of the text.

Is there some kind of parameter somewhere in the code by which we can adjust the speed of scroll in this case?

Here's the code:

```
var inputBox = document.createElement("textarea");

inputBox.className = 'propendFormInput';
inputBox.value = ourObject.getDescription();
inputBox.rows = 8;

div.appendChild(inputBox);
```

in war/js/diagramly/Dialogs.js